# how to quickly add a webpart

Tags: managed-metadata, promoted-links, tiles

I have built a web app from the promoted link view to act as a navbar.
This contain a list of webpage address with a metadata managed field to tell me which pages this tile should be shown.

I want to know if there is a way to write using html to paste the webpart into a page and just modify the filter statement without having to go though several page to create new views.

or else

just add the webpart and know that if it on a certain page just show certain tile from the metadata

thanks